# Springboot - Connect exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I used this code in a springboot application :

```
try {
            System.out.println("StartListener.onApplicationEvent()");
            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().GET()
                    .uri(URI.create(
                            "https://fr.ftp.opendatasoft.com/openscol/fr-en-calendrier-scolaire/Zone-A-B-C-Corse.ics"))
                    .build();
            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder().version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2).build();
            HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            System.out.println(response.body());
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

i have a connect exception every time :

> java.net.ConnectException     at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:573)
> at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:123)
> at
> fr.utensilia.covoit.back.config.StartListener.onApplicationEvent(StartListener.java:42)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at
> org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:344)
> at
> org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:229)
> at
> org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:166)
> at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
> at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
> at
> org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:938)
> at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
> at
> fr.utensilia.covoit.CovoitApplication.main(CovoitApplication.java:10)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at
> org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException  at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.Utils.toConnectException(Utils.java:1047)
> at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.PlainHttpConnection.connectAsync(PlainHttpConnection.java:198)
> at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.PlainHttpConnection.checkRetryConnect(PlainHttpConnection.java:230)
> at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.PlainHttpConnection.lambda$connectAsync$1(PlainHttpConnection.java:206)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:934)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:911)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1773)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) Caused by:
> java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException  at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.ensureOpen(SocketChannelImpl.java:195)
> at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.beginConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:760)
> at
> java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:848)
> at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.PlainHttpConnection.lambda$connectAsync$0(PlainHttpConnection.java:183)
> at
> java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569)
> at
> java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.PlainHttpConnection.connectAsync(PlainHttpConnection.java:185)
> ... 9 more

If i use the same code in a simple class (without spring) it's ok :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("StartListener.onApplicationEvent()");
            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().GET()
                    .uri(URI.create(
                            "https://fr.ftp.opendatasoft.com/openscol/fr-en-calendrier-scolaire/Zone-A-B-C-Corse.ics"))
                    .build();
            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder().version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2).build();
            HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            System.out.println(response.body());
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I can open it in a browser and exception is not similar to this one : [java.net.ConnectException while Source Validation in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72688051/java-net-connectexception-while-source-validation-in-java)

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Pffffff !!

I had a proxy on my vm arguments ... it works without